# Why do many teachers say that singing in pure chest voice is what is easiest for singers?

Tags: voice

I sometimes read or hear people, mostly teachers, saying that singing in pure chest voice is what is most easiest for a singer. When I sing my easiest notes I sing a little higher and don't use pure chest voice.  I don't really like pure chest voice. Perhaps I use what some call mix voice. It's confusing why they would say thigs like this if it isn't true for all people. To me this sounds a bit like "one size fits all" but I am not an expert at all so I should not have a specific opinion.
Two examples:

1. I went to a choir director for an audition. She asked me to sing a certain melody. I said that F#m is the key for me. She told me to sing it in Em.
2. I went to a singing teacher who would play hymns on her piano. She told me to sing them in the key they are written in in. Hymn books have keys for low voices. I did not like it. I sometimes wanted to sing a major third higher.
   SHe never told me I Should sing much higher.

Why do many teachers say that singing in pure chest voice is what is easiest for singers?

Comment: It's the one that most singers use most of the time. More natural to use chest voice.

Comment: Perhaps the choir director and your teacher were trying to get you to **read sheet music** and **sing as directed** instead of sing lower. Singing music with others forces you to pick the same key as everyone else if you want the end result to sound good.

Answer (score 0):

To sing properly even the lowest notes in your register should resonate in the head, and the highest notes in your register should resonate in your chest.  The air should never be restricted to one place or the other.  However, for lower pitch notes you can get a good tone and supported volume without proper resonance in your head.  I think this is what is meant by a "pure chest voice".  It is not proper technique but you won't really feel or hear anything wrong with it.  In contrast, when you sing at the higher end of your register you must have the resonance in the head.  You can feel it buzz in the sinus cavity, behind the eyes (what some people call the third eye, which I don't believe in but only use for descriptive purposes here).  If a singer does not get the resonance in the right place the resulting notes will come out unstable in both timbre and intonation, and the throat will start to become strained.  For many voice students (myself included) getting this head resonance can be difficult at first.  Once you get the technique down correctly and in your muscle memory you find that you can sing in both voices through your entire range and not go through any awkward transitions.

Based on what you have written I don't interpret the comments as a one size fits all for singing, but merely a statement of fact for many people.  That chest voice is "easy".  That doesn't mean it's correct.  Many self taught singers think they can sing in higher registers but in reality they just sound nasally and have weak unsupported tone in that range.  I call it the Julia Child voice.  Also, with enough training many singers find that they don't have problems singing in different keys.  Most tunes do not have a very wide range in frequency, maybe within an octave with an occasional high note.  With a two and a half octave range one should be able to sing a song in any key.  I am sure there are exception to this.

Comment: but Julia Child did talk like that for comical purposes, right? I never heard of her until today.

Comment: @andrewjohnsson, she's a chef, and a very famous one (perhaps you are being sarcastic).  When I first started classical voice training I complained to my teacher that I thought I sounded like Dan Aykroyd imitating Julia Child (a staple on SNL in the 70s).  I eventually got over that.

Comment: I am not sarcastic. She sounded like a comedian.

Comment: I see.  No, she is one of the most famous chef's in America, credited for bringing French cooking to middle America with one of the earliest cooking shows.  She was quite a personality and her size, and voice, got mocked a lot.  Look up Dan Aykroyd doing her.